# Checking for non-common strings between two lists in Python

Tags: python, string, list

Let's say that I have lists `list_1=['a','b','c','d','e','f']` and `list_2=['a','b','c','d']`. I would like to know a method so that I can check automatically which strings are absent in `list_2` but present in `list_1`. This is to be done on much longer lists.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`set.difference`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference) for the task:

```
list_1=['a','b','c','d','e','f']
list_2=['a','b','c','d']

print( set(list_1).difference(list_2) )
```

Prints:

```
{'e', 'f'}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
answer = set(list_1) - set(list_2)
```

This should work for you

Answer (score 0):

Once more method to get your desired output:

```
d=['a','b','c','d','e','f']
e=['a','b','c','d']
f=[]
for  i in d:
   if (i not in e):
       f.append(i)
print(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create your resulting set using a set comprehension:

```
result = {item for item in list_1 if item not in list_2}
print(result)
{'e', 'f'}
```